# Why is a proxy object created when you try to access the same web3 object outside of the scope where it was created?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have two functions, called one after another. The first one called creates a new Web3 object and sets it to window.web3:

```
  async loadWeb3() {
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        console.log(window.web3);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
       }
    });
  }
```

Next, my program calls another function, which tries to access the web3 object which is set to `window.web3`. Here it is:

```
  async loadBlockchainData() {
    console.log(window.web3);
  }
```

So to sum it up, I create a new Web3 object and set it to `window.web3` in one function, log it to the console and then in a different function, I log this same object. Here's the catch, you can't do any of the typical things like `window.web3.eth.getAccounts()` within the `loadBlockchainData()` function. This is because in the `loadBlockchainData()` function, `window.web3` becomes a proxy object, and is different from the same window.web3 that is defined in the `loadWeb3()` method. You can try it out yourself.

My question is, why does window.web3 become a proxy object, what makes it a proxy object (metamask? web3.js?), and how do we interact with this proxy object using the web3.js library?

Comment: It is a normal javascript behavior, both are async function so one of them may run while the other hasn't finished. `loadWeb3` attaches a function to 'load' event so it is likely `loadBlockchainData` runs before `loadWeb3` has finished. The proxy is created by metamask when injecting into the pages. Since several iterations using 'load' event is no longer the recommended procedure. Read their [Getting started guide](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations).

Comment: Ah I see. You are right, the ```loadBlockchainData``` runs before the other function has finished. Does JS automatically make anything returned from an async function a proxy? Is that what is happening? Or is the proxy created by metamask? I'm confused since you say it is normal JS behavior but also created by metamask. Thanks!

Comment: The normal js behavior relates how async function are executed. The proxy is metamask way of dealing with web3 deprecation, it is in their blog announcement.